# How do I properly connect Google Pay?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, payment-processing, google-pay

Could you please help me? I need to connect Google Pay to the application. But when I run the application I get ExceptionInInitializerError. Debug says that PaymentsClient is null.
Could you please show how to properly initialize PaymentsClient? I do it inside the Fragmnt and pass the activity to it.

```
class PremiumFragment {

    private lateinit var paymentsClient: PaymentsClient

    override fun init() {
        paymentsClient = PaymentsUtil.createPaymentsClient(requireActivity())
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        checkReadinessToPay()
    }

    private fun checkReadinessToPay() {
        val isReadyToPayJson = PaymentsUtil.isReadyToPayRequest() ?: return
        val request = IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(isReadyToPayJson.toString()) ?: return

        val task: Task<Boolean> = paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request)
        task.addOnCompleteListener { completedTask ->
            if (completedTask.isSuccessful) {
                val result = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                isReadyToPay(result)
            } else {
                // Handle error
                val exception = completedTask.exception
                // Log or handle the exception accordingly
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already had a look here: https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart/blob/master/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/util/PaymentsUtil.kt#L173